# ngIf changing the alignment everytime

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

```
<div fxLayout="row style="padding-top: 2rem;padding-left: 10%;"
     fxLayoutAlign="space around"  fxLayoutGap="2%">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="2%">
    <mat-card (click)="onClickShowChart1($event)" style="height: 55%;">
      <mat-card-header>{{A}}</mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>A</mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card (click)="onClickShowChart2($event)" style="height: 55%;" >
     <mat-card-header>{{R}}</mat-card-header>
     <mat-card-content>R</mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="showChart1">
    <chart Code....>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="showChart2">
    <chart Code....>
  </div>
</div>
```

in my component.ts file i have mentioned the functions

```
onClickShowChart2(event) {
    this.showChart1=false
    this.showChart2=true
}
onClickShowChart1(event) {
    this.showChart1=true
    this.showChart2=false
}
```

its working as expected but everytime it changes its changing the structure of the mat-card for a split second ..

Comment: Can you share the images of what you really mean, how is the structure changing?

Comment: Next time, please use the appropriate code block/fence. That is not how you format code.

Comment: Will the charts ever be displayed at the same? Or can only one chart be displayed at a time?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer yes only one at a time once i click the mat-card

Comment: @WahabShah- yes i mean that the lower divs are coming up when the chart is loading and once its loaded they are in their previous place again

Comment: @DaneBrouwer yes only one at a time once i click the mat-card abd once i click it thw correct chart is showing but in the transition time, the lower divs that have other content, are coming up in that period and then again going back once the chart gets loaded fully

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reason for the same is ngIf is a structural directive.When the condition is false, the div does not appear but when the condition is true, the div comes to the dom and may change the alignment.Try using ng-container rather than div tag.

Comment: okay any alternative to that? like i have used the [hidden] property but the problem is still there

Comment: [hidden] might not resolve the issue.You tried using ng-container? Give the stackblitz link of your code.